# Strange behaviour of IntersectingQ

Tags: numerics, numerical-value, numeric-array

I wanted to check whether two lists of complex numbers have an element in common and stumbled upon this rather strange behaviour of the function `IntersectingQ`. If I evaluate

```
a = {Sqrt[1 + I]/2^(1/4)};
b = {E^((I Pi)/8)};
a == b
a === b
IntersectingQ[a, b]
```

I get

```
True
False
False
```

This is to be expected since it is not obvious the two symbolic expressions are equal. (I assume Mathematica uses `===` to check equality)
On the other hand, when I evaluate

```
na = N[a, {10, Infinity}]
nb = N[b, {10, Infinity}]
na == nb
na === nb
IntersectingQ[na, nb]
```

I get

```
True
True
False
```

The `FullForm` of `na` and `nb` reveals some hints:

```
List[Complex[0.92387953251128671108757291051542624466`10.116130343752937,0.38268343236508975307202834895670782981`9.733354658415074]]
List[Complex[0.92387953251128675612818318939678828682`10.116130343752937,0.38268343236508977172845998403039886676`9.733354658415074]]
```

namely the real parts of the two numbers are different from the 17th digit onward. So I wonder:

1. What test does `IntersectingQ` use to determine whether two expressions are equal, and
2. how can I test whether two lists of complex numbers intersect, up to a certain accuracy (and Infinite precision)?

Comment: According to the [current documentation for IntersectingQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntersectingQ.html) for Version 13.1, one can specify the test, for example `SameTest->Equal` or `SameTest->SameQ`.

Comment: Your observation that the default test is not `SameQ` is surprising. Related functions such as [DeleteDuplicates](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html) use `SameQ` by default. Looks like a small inconsistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the accuracy and precision of na and nb:

```
na = N[a, {10, Infinity}]
nb = N[b, {10, Infinity}]
{Accuracy[#], Precision[#]} & /@ {na, nb}
(*{{10., 10.}, {10., 10.}}*)
```

Therefore, only 10 digits after the decimal point are taken into consideration. If the numbers differ by 10^-10 or smaller, they are considered equal by SameQ and Equal, therefore:

```
na == nb
na === nb
(* True, True*)
```

However, by default IntersectingQ seems to compare using machine precision, that is precision==16:

```
IntersectingQ[{1. + 10^-16}, {1.}]
IntersectingQ[{1. + 10^-15}, {1.}]
(* True, False *)
```

And even if we reduce the precision the comparison is still done with precision 16:

```
IntersectingQ[N[{1. + 10^-16}, {10, 10}], {1.}]
IntersectingQ[N[{1. + 10^-15}, {10, 10}], {1.}]
(* True, False *)
```

You can change this behavior by using the third argument of IntersectingQ

```
IntersectingQ[na, nb, SameTest -> Equal]
IntersectingQ[na, nb, SameTest -> SameQ]
(* True, True*)
```

Now the precision is taken into account.